# My marker appears but not my cluster (markerclusterer)

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project for my school. I'm using markerclusterer and google map api and jcdecaux api for the town of Lyon.

My marker appears but not my cluster for group my marker

I hope my English is correct

```js
var points = [];
var apiUrl = 'https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Lyon&apiKey=032fe8f843b38aa80bdc36113d5e2bd892a58bae';
ajaxGet(apiUrl, function(reponse) {
  var stations = JSON.parse(reponse);
  stations.forEach(function(station) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: station.position,
      map: map,
      title: station.name
    });
    points.push(marker);
  })
})

var map;

var mcOptions = {
  gridSize: 50,
  maxZoom: 30,
  imagePath: '../image/m'
};

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 45.764013,
      lng: 4.849933
    }
  });
  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: '.../image/m',
    gridSize: 50,
    maxZoom: 5
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding markerClusterer.addMarkers(Marker[]) to give the markers to the clusterer. Start with [] for the second parameter of MarkerClusterer, and add them afterwards.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site. Please answer in English.